# Shell, if statment of variable only containing alphabet?

Tags: shell

how do i write of if statement that does

```
If [[$word contain character other than alphabet]]
   echo "stop"
fi
```

Comment: `[[ $word = *[![:alpha:]]* ]] && echo "stop"`

Comment: The linked duplicate is for "alphanumeric", but take out the numeric bits of the spec from any answer there and you have an alpha-characters-only answer.

Comment: btw, as you can see in the first comment above, `[[ ]]` is not part of `if`; you can use it without `if`, just as you can use `if` to test exit status of commands other than `[[` or `[`.